# GroupBy with Where clause LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq

I have a question, I want to use Group by with Where clause. Here is the scenario, I want get all the orders of a user and group by them with ordernumber so it doesn't show me multiple orders with same order number. I tried to use LINQ query but that doesn't seemed to work. Does anyone have any idea?

```
var result = Entity.Where(x => x.UserId == Guid.Parse(userId)).GroupBy(x => x.OrderNumber).ToList();
```

This is what I tried.

Comment: What did you say `but that doesn't seemed to work`, Is there any exception or didn't work as your expect

Comment: There is some exception cos it can't convert to list object. The return type is IGroupable<string, object> but I want it to be list

Comment: What's your expect result? I think you can try to use linq `select`

Answer (score 1):

You can get first record from group.

```cs
var result = Entity
   .Where(x => x.UserId == Guid.Parse(userId))
   .GroupBy(x => x.OrderNumber)
   .Select(g => g.First())
   .ToList();
```

Comment: What about I need all the records of select user? For example if has multiple orders with suppose 3 orders have same order number and 5 orders have some order number and I need both, will it work?

Comment: Why to do not test? You will get two orders.